# AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: pandas, plot, format, styles

I worked on a database of skill workers in different courses and now I want to evaluate success in three different courses. After group by on databaase I get the below result:

```
     Courses:    
1   0.5882
2   0.2195
3   0.2857
```

I used style.format to change format value as percentage:

```
'style.format({'Courses': '{:,.2%}'.format})':
```

```
  Courses:
1   58.82%
2   21.95%
3   28.57%
```

Now, for plot this values, I got the below error, how can I solve this problem?

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Comment: plot original column `df.Courses`

Comment: I want to plot in percentage format.